# IE problem displaying the .dialog modal box with Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I am very new to javascript and have been using the JQuery library quite a bit.  I have a dialog box that should open when I click a button on the page.  That part is working fine but when I added the javascript to close the dialog box on click of a submit button inside the dialog box, the dialog box will not open at all.  (Works fine is all browsers except Internet Explorer).  Can you guys help?  Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(".callparser").click(function (e) {
$(".parserinformation").dialog({
    modal: true,
    minHeight:400,
    minWidth: 580,
    open: function (e, ui) {
    var $container = $(this);
    $container.find('#close').click(function(){
        $container.dialog("close");
    });
    },
    beforeClose: function (e, ui) {
    var $container = $(this);
    $container.find('#close').unbind('click');
    },
    });

});
});
   </script>
```

Here is the html (simplified):

```
<input type="button" name="Parser" class="callparser" value="Parser"/>




<div class="parserinformation"  style="display: none;"> 
<div class="addtofolder">
     <input type="submit" id="close" class="addtofolderbutton" value="Private" onclick="$.jGrowl('Your product has been added!')">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "when I added the javascript to close the dialog box on click of a submit button inside the dialog box, the dialog box will not open at all." Are you trying to open it or close it?

Comment: I have a submit button to close the dialog box.  However, when I put the code to close the button on click, the original dialog box won't even open now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without the last comma (`,`), IE doesn't like it after the last element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".callparser").click(function (e) {
            $(".parserinformation").dialog({
                modal: true,
                minHeight:400,
                minWidth: 580,
                open: function (e, ui) {
                    var $container = $(this);
                    $container.find('#close').click(function(){
                        $container.dialog("close");
                    });
                },
                beforeClose: function (e, ui) {
                    var $container = $(this);
                    $container.find('#close').unbind('click');
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>

<input type="button" name="Parser" class="callparser" value="Parser"/>

<div class="parserinformation"  style="display: none;">
    <div class="addtofolder">
        <input type="submit" id="close" class="addtofolderbutton" value="Private" onclick="$.jGrowl('Your product has been added!')">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me but it didn't change anything. I removed the comma and still not opening.

Comment: Maybe your IE is cached your js file, try to clean the cache (works fine with the removed comma in IE6, IE7 and IE8).